# How to use pointers in an union in C?

Tags: c, pointers, initialization, unions

I want to initialize this structure:

```
typedef struct
{
    int num;
    union 
    {
        const char** ppStrList;
        const char* pStr;
    };
    union
    {
        int num1;
        int num2;
    };
} tMyStruct;
```

If I try to initialize this structure when I declare the variable I get an error: For example;

```
const char *gpStr = "str";

const char *gpStrList[2] =
{
    {"str1"},
    {"str2"}
};

tMyStruct myStruct[2] = 
{
    {0,{gpStrList},{3}},
    {1,{gpStr},{4}}
};
```

The variable `gpStr` can´t be used to initialize the structure

But it can be initialized inside of a function without problem:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    myStruct[0].num = 0;
    myStruct[0].ppStrList = gpStrList;
    myStruct[0].num1 = 3;

    myStruct[1].num = 0;
    myStruct[1].pStr = gpStr;
    myStruct[1].num2 = 3;
}
```

Why the structure can't be initialized when it is declared?

I think the union has a special behavior because if I don’t use an union the problem doesn’t exist. For example:

```
typedef struct
{
    int num;
    union /* Union to contain ppStrList and pStr pointers */
    {
        const char** ppStrList;
        const char* pStr;
    };
    union
    {
        int num1;
        int num2;
    };
} tMyStruct1;


typedef struct
{
    int num;
    /* I don´t use an union */
    const char** ppStrList;
    const char* pStr;

    union
    {
        int num1;
        int num2;
    };
} tMyStruct2;

const char gStr[] = "str";

const char *gpStrList[2] = 
{
    {"str1"},
    {"str2"}
};

tMyStruct1 myStruct1[2] = /* Structure with union inside */
{

    {0,{gpStrList},{3}},
    {1,{gStr},{4}}  /* <--- Error here if I use gStr address with union */
};

tMyStruct2 myStruct2[2] = /* Structure without union inside */
{
    {0,gpStrList,NULL,{3}},
    {1,NULL,gStr,{4}} /* <--- No poblem here if I use gStr address */
};
```

Comment: I daresay that this:

`union
    {
        int num1;
        int num2;
    };`

proves that you should not be using an union at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variables initialized at file scope (whether `static` or not) and variables initialized at block scope with `static` duration can only be initialized with constants.  Automatic variables (necessarily at block scope) can be initialized with expressions.

Also, when a union is initialized, the initializer must match the first member unless a designated initializer is used.  With C99 or later, you could write:

```
typedef struct
{
    int num;
    union 
    {
        const char** ppStrList;
        const char* pStr;
    };
    union
    {
        int num1;
        int num2;
    };
} tMyStruct;

const char gpStr[] = "str";

const char *gpStrList[2] =
{
    "str1",
    "str2"
};

tMyStruct myStruct[2] = 
{
    { .num = 0, { .ppStrList = gpStrList }, { .num1 = 3 } },
    { .num = 1, { .pStr      = gpStr     }, { .num2 = 4 } },
};
```

Note the tweaked type for `gpStr`. You don't have to use the designated initializers for all the elements, but consistency suggests you probably should.  Also note that a union of two differently named `int` members is modestly pointless.  The different elements of a union should normally be of different types.

Comment: Far clearer and more complete than my modest contribution! Gets my vote!

Comment: I must use a designated initializer to initialize the `union`. About the `union` of two differently named `int` members. I am agree, Just to clarify, the code represents a real problem but this code was created only for didactic purposes.

Comment: @leiva: fair enough, and not very surprising. It was only a minor discussion point.  You can head off such comments if you need to ask again by making sure you use two diverse types (`int` and `char *`, perhaps) in the extra union, or by leaving the second union out of the example.

Comment: I have a question. Does pointers inside a Union shares the same memory location or not?

Comment: It depends on how the union is organized, @Naasif.  Yes, no, maybe — the 'maybe' arising because it isn't clear what organization you're thinking of.  If the union is `union u_ptr { char *cp; double *dp; };` then yes, the pointers share the same memory location.  For other unions, it depends on the definition.  For example, `union u_pqr { struct s_pqr { char *cp; double *dp; }; int data[4]; };` the two pointers do not share the same memory location.  If that isn't sufficient help, ask a new question, please (rather than asking in comments to this answer, or this question).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler  Thank you for your response. I was talking about the last example code of the article. Here is the link, https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/union-c/

Comment: @Naasif — the `union u_pqr` in my previous comment is analogous to the last example in the GeeksForGeeks article.  Those pointers are separate.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Ah, I have posted a question including all details. I would request you to pay a visit on my post! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60621603/do-pointers-inside-a-union-share-same-memory-location

Answer (score 0):

The unscientific answer:

I think you can only initialize with constants. In the first instance you are initializing (i.e. allocating a value before the program runs) with a variable; by definition variables don't have a "accessible" value until the program runs. In your second example the "initialization" is really an "assignment" with a variable, and that's OK. I don't think it has anything to do with the fact that you have a union.

Simplest example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int one = 1;
int two = one;
int main(void) {
  printf("one is %d; two is %d\n", one, two);
}
```

When I try to compile, I get

```
consts.c:3: error: initializer element is not constant
```

I hope this clarifies things.

Comment: Curious that the very next question tagged "C" has as title "warning: initializer element is not constant"… there's an epidemic, apparently!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can only initialize the FIRST element of a union, unless you use an explicit designator.  So the following works:

```
tMyStruct myStruct[2] =
{
    {0,{gpStrList},{3}},
    {1,{.pStr = "str"},{4}}
};
```