# Do pointers inside a union share same memory location?

Tags: c, union

I was going through an **[article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/union-c/)** to learn about union and I had understood that the size of a Union depends upon the largest variable size and the variables share the same memory. So the concept was pretty clear for me but in the article author said that using "union" for a binary tree was worthwhile when it had two pointers to point other two child. A question arose in my mind for the "What are applications of union?" section of that article, what would be the possible explanations for pointers inside a union? The link has been given below.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/union-c/

So, this is it. Is there anybody who can help me out?

Comment: They are using a union to either store the data or to store a tree node, but not both at the same time.

Comment: *what would be the possible explanations for pointers inside a union?*  The linked example has two pointers inside a `struct`, not two pointers inside a `union`.

Comment: That source is wrong; the size of a union is not always the size of the largest member. It is at least the size of the largest member extended so that the union has the alignment required for all of its members.

Comment: @EricPostpischil  You said " the size of a union is not always the size of the largest member" Would you please explain bit more?

Comment: @Naasif: If a union has a ten-`char` array member, its size must be at least ten bytes. If it also has a `double` member that requires an alignment of eight bytes, then its size must be a multiple of eight bytes. These two requirements combine to require a size of at least 16 bytes. So the size of the union in this case is larger than the size of its largest member.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yeah, yeah. Thank you so much! But to me "alignment" concept was not much clear. Bit confusing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> in the article author said that using "union" for a binary tree is worthwhile when it had two pointers to point other two child...what would be the possible explanations for pointers inside a union?

I believe you are talking about this code snippet:

```
struct NODE { 
    bool is_leaf; 
    union { 
        struct
        { 
            struct NODE* left; 
            struct NODE* right; 
        } internal; 
        double data; 
    } info; 
};
```

You misunderstand the author's intent here. They are using a union to implement the two different kinds of nodes in a tree: an internal node that has a left and right pointer and a leaf node which has data. This union shares memory between a `struct` and a `double`. It does **not** share memory between the left and right pointers.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your answer and I am sorry for my mistake. But still there is something to think about. Memory location is being shared between struct and double. So, if I put any any value on data, it's going to be written on the "Union" I just like to know how will it work? Thank you again

Comment: @Naasif You can declare `NODE n;` and then assign `n.info.data = 42.0` for example.

Answer (score 0):

I'd also inject that I really don't agree with this author.  Just define a `struct` with two pointers and data, and be done.  Use `calloc()` to obtain the structure and set it all to binary zeros.  There's no point in "saving a few bytes of memory" anymore.  If you use a `union` in this way, you *are going to* screw-up and waste a lot of time debugging.

Answer (score -1):

**§6.7.2.1 - 16** [ISO/IEC 9899:2017](https://web.archive.org/web/20181230041359if_/http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/abq/c17_updated_proposed_fdis.pdf)

> The size of a union is sufficient to contain the largest of its members. **The value of at most one of the members can be stored in a union object at any time. A pointer to a union object, suitably converted, points to each of its members** (or if a member is a bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides), andvice versa.

So yes, all the members of the union, being pointers or other, all share the same address which is consistent with how unions work.

Tested here:

https://wandbox.org/permlink/XdGY4Mrz0gQCfrbv